# Get Key correspondent of a value from when a ModelState.IsValid is false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to get the key correspondent of the value with error. I can use foreach to get all errors in ModelState but how to associate it with your respective keys to get these names (keys names or index)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the ModelState (which is a ModelStateDictionary) and look at the keys, they correspond to the properties

Answer (score 0):

Yishai's answer is not that straightforward for me, so I thought of leaving the following for others ending up here.

The following is a method I wrote to return all ModelStateDictionary errors, including the key where the error was found.

```
   public static String GetErrorsJoined(this ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary, String separator = ". ")
    {
        String errorsJoined = String.Empty;
        List<String> errors = new List<string>();

        try
        {

            foreach(KeyValuePair<String, ModelState> keyValuePair in modelStateDictionary)
            {
                if (keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    Int32 keyDelimiterIndex = keyValuePair.Key.IndexOf('.');
                    String realKey = (keyDelimiterIndex > -1 && keyDelimiterIndex + 1 <= keyValuePair.Key.Length - 1) ? keyValuePair.Key.Substring(keyDelimiterIndex + 1) : keyValuePair.Key;
                    IEnumerable<String> keyErrors = keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Select(error => String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", error.ErrorMessage, separator, error.Exception.Message));
                    errors.Add(String.Format("Field [{0}]: {1}", realKey, String.Join(separator, keyErrors)));
                }
            }

            errorsJoined = String.Join(separator, errors);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do something
        }

        return errorsJoined;
    }
```